# What is the syntax for using pandoc with RStudio Markdown for conversion to MS Word? How can it be used to include bibliography and inline citations?

Tags: r, knitr, rstudio, r-markdown

RStudio now supports directly knitting .Rmd files into docx format --pure gold for someone who is the technical side of most collaborations where the final revisions of the article are going to be done in Word.

However, I had just barely figured out how to get R, knitr, and pandoc to play with each other and so I am looking for some help in making the transition while the documentation is still in its infancy.

My file converts with no problem using the yaml code block as follows:

```
---
title: "Testing"
output: 
  word_document:
    fig_width: 5
    fig_height: 5
    fig_caption: true
---
```

and the [documentation](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/) says that, assuming I have a file 'myLibrary.bib' in the same directory as my .Rmd file, I should be able to add something like this:

```
    pandoc_args: [
      bibliography: "myLibrary.bib"
    ]
```

or

```
pandoc_args: [
      --bibliography "myLibrary.bib"
    ]
```

but I can't seem to find any examples of how to format this in the obvious places: [here](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/word_document_format.html)
or [here](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html)

Bonus points for code that also links the bibliography to the myJournalFormat.csl file also in the same folder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to enclose  your arguments in  quotation marks, (`""`) and be separated by commas

If I have a bibliography file called `biblio.bib` and the `csl` file is `chicago-author-date.csl`,

the following will front matter will work

```
---
title: "Example Doc"
output:
  word_document:
    pandoc_args: [
      "--csl", "chicago-author-date.csl",
      "--bibliography", "biblio.bib"
    ]
---
```

Comment: and +1 for the bonus .csl response. I knew it couldn't be too far off, but couldn't quite get how the parser was working. Thanks!

Comment: note `bibliography` can also be a top-level field in the metadata

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem you have. Perhaps not a real answer to your question, but you might want to take a look at David Gohel's r package ReporteRs http://davidgohel.github.io/ReporteRs/gettingstarted.html He made it easy to let r generate .docx files. I have already had astonishing results!